Prove that $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{x_i} \right) \geq \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{n-x_i}{1-x_i} \right)$ for positive $x_i$, $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$
I encountered a problem asking me to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+\frac{1}{x_i} \right) \geq \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{n-x_i}{1-x_i} \right)$ for positive $x_i$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$. I tried to approach the problem via induction:
If we assume that the claim is true for $n$, then we could WLOG suppose that $X_{n}=u+v$ for $u=x_{n}, v=x_{n+1}$ where $X_n$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ term in $x_1,\ldots x_n$ and $x_i$ denotes the $i^{\text{th}}$ term in $x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}$. We want to show that
$\begin{equation}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{x_i}\right)\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{v}\right)\geq \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n+1-x_i}{1-x_i}\right)\right)\cdot\frac{n+1-u}{1-u}\cdot \frac{n+1-v}{1-v}.\end{equation}$
I don’t see how this simplifies the proof. Can anyone show me how to proceed? Thank you.

On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h299899p1825735

The naive induction approach doesn't strike me as one I'd try, due to the difficulty of relating $ \frac{ n-x_i } { 1 - x_i } $ to $ \frac{ n+1 - x_i } { 1 - x_i } $. $\quad$ I might give the forward-backward induction approach a try, though it still isn't immediately apparent to me how I'd get started.
